# Referencing the home directory in CLI PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface

The following examples don't work in php -

```
$data = file_get_contents('~/Documents/someFile.txt');
```

//no such file or directory

```
$data = file_get_contents('$HOME/Documents/someFile.txt');
```

// no such file or directory

What's the reason why this doesn't work?

Comment: Just based on the error report - those files don't exist where you think they do?

Comment: `'$HOME/Documents/someFile.txt'` - variables don't get parsed in single quotes, the `$HOME`'s value is unknown.

Comment: `'~/` you're trying to get this from a shared server. You need to use a full system path.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of `~` and `$HOME` is done by your shell, not by PHP. Depending on your config, you can probably use:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['HOME'] . '/Documents/someFile.txt');
```

Comment: Is `$_SERVER` normally set in CLI PHP?

Comment: Yep, though YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getenv('HOME')` or `$_SERVER['HOME']`.  You cannot use $HOME in single quotes because its literal will be used, and ~ isn't known by php.

Comment: Thanks. that works. I was purposefully trying to use it in single quote as its not a PHP variable. I thought it would work as string in command line. Clearly, I need more research into using php in the cli.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file_get_contents('$HOME/Documents/someFile.txt');
```

has two problems:

1. You never set the variable `$HOME`. `HOME` is an environment variable, but they don't automatically become PHP variables like they do in the shell.
2. Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, see [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) (not coincidentally, this is the same as the shell).

You can do:

```
$HOME = getenv('HOME');
$data = file_get_contents("$HOME/Documents/someFile.txt");
```

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of the differences between single/double quotes in both php and bash. I didn't however realize I had to pass the $HOME environment variable to PHP.  My thought was to simply pass the path to file_get_contents as string as I would normally navigate in cli.

Comment: But in the CLI `$HOME` is a variable that has to be replaced with its value.